# asdf installed on server works when ssh-ed from terminal but doesn't when accessed from github actions

Tags: bash, ssh

I have asdf version manager installed on Digital Ocean VPS and works as expected when I ssh into the VPS. However, when using [github actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ssh-remote-commands) to execute remote commands in VPS using ssh, it says:
`asdf: command not found` (same error for executing npm, elixir, erlang etc. which are installed inside asdf)

I do have `. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh` in .profile and
`. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash` in .bashrc but still doesn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can user this:
`ssh user@host ". /home/user/.asdf/asdf.sh" && you_command`